# Сайт на Node.js долго грузиться после определенного времени простоя

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, mongodb, производительность, mongoose

Суть проблемы в том, что сайт, после простоя(30м-1ч без запросов) при первой загрузке долго грузиться(6-8 секунд). Сначала думал, что это из-за бд, я использовал кластер на облаке mongodb. Поставил базу локально на сервер с сайтом, скорость, конечно улучшилась в разы, но проблема не исчезла. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: heroku?_________

Comment: Расставьте в приложении вывод времени по всей цепочки загрузки, откройте параллельно консоль разработчика на вкладке нетворк и смотрите, на какой операции у вас дольше всего работает. Там уже позже можно точечно копать